# Adding external IDs to primary key field

Tags: ms-access, database-design, primary-key

I am creating a database for a university dept(for internal use) and this database tracks issues related to people. I get information of only employees at the university and I am tracking them using their university ID. But the database is also intended for people who are not employees at the university or even sometimes people outside the university. I want to assign an ID to these people but store values within same column as university id. Any ideas how I should tackle this issue? I don't know how to keep the univ id and the no. I am going to give to the others in the same column and yet treat them differently (when needed). How do people usually tackle such issues?

PS:  I do not like auto numbers since I cannot delete an ID and get it back into the database

Comment: For an employee, does the university ID has to match the externally visible ID?

Comment: It does not. The ID I am going to generate for external people is for my convenience

Comment: I was asking about non-external people.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is probably to create a common `Person` table for all people which simply tracks an Id, then relate separate tables for each of the different kinds of people (ex. `Employee`, `Student`, etc.) to it - *note that all of these names are just examples*. Each of these tables would contain a foreign key to the `Person` table. In effect, this logically make each of them a different "subclass" of person.

For example, `Employee` my be related to `Person` via the foreign key

```
[Person.PersonId] {PK}  <==(1-0)==>  {FK:Person.PersonId} Employee.PersonId
```

This is generic for any `Other` entity:

```
[Person.PersonId] {PK}  <==(1-0)==>  {FK:Person.PersonId} Other.PersonId
```

Note that any columns common to all types of person may exist directly on the `Person` table, with each of the "subclasses" of person only recording columns specific to its particular type.

In addition, you may create a view with joins these tables to present a "combined" generic record for people. In some cases, it's useful to include a column in the view that simply indicates which table an individual record came from (ex, `class` or `type`.

Comment: See also the info tab at [Tag:class-table-inheritance]

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not want to mix the two different kind of ids within one field. This is just waiting for trouble when you migrate since you need to keep these apart by convention or through other fields.

You will of course use the uni id to search the person ...

(uni id and an id for people not on uni)

Approach 1 - introduce an additional table

```
Issue
- id
- person_id 

Person
- id
- university_person_id (optional)

University Person (table)
- id
```

Approach 2 - make the university ref id optional

```
Issue
- person_id 

Person
- id
- university_ref (optional)
```

What do you think?

But if you really want to go along with mixing the two kind of ids within one field I suggest to use a prefix followed by a generated number.

```
EXTERNAL-123456
```

You can also introduce an additional field external_contact (boolean) or contact_type 'Uni' or 'External'. Also add a unique index on the two combined.

Hope this will give you some food for thought :)